# how to loop over each pixel to calculate Koppen geiger class?

Tags: matlab

I have two NETCDF files with dimension of 712,652,12 i would like to calculate koppen class for each pixel so that i wrote for loop to calculate that . i wrote for loop to calculate pixel wise but i got error like    "Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-1 and the size of the right side is 712-by-652.

Error in koppen_calculate (line 74)
Class(lat, lon) = pixel_Class;"

here is my code

```
% Check dimensions
[lat_temp, lon_temp, time_temp] = size(T);
[lat_precip, lon_precip, time_precip] = size(P);

% Get the dimensions of the data (latitude, longitude, and time)
%[latitude, longitude, ] = size(T);

%[n_lon, n_lat] = size(T);
%Koppen = cell(n_lon, n_lat);
% Create arrays to store the results
Class = zeros(lat_temp, lon_temp );
BroadClass = zeros(lat_temp, lon_temp );
% Iterate over data points
for lon = 1:lon_temp
    for lat = 1:lat_temp
        Te = T(lon, lat);  % Temperature values
        Pr = P(lon, lat);  % Precipitation values

        % Calculate Koppen classification for the data point
        %Koppen{lon, lat} = calculate_koppen(Te, Pr);
        [pixel_Class, pixel_BroadClass] = KoppenGeiger(Te, Pr, classes);
        % Store the results in the corresponding location in the result arrays
        Class(lat, lon) = pixel_Class;
        BroadClass(lat, lon) = pixel_BroadClass;
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't see a built-in function `KoppenGeiger()` in MATLAB, but whatever it is, it's obviously returning a 712-by-652 array in `pixel_Class`.

Comment: yeah .. but i want save pixel class value in class array with corresponding lat lon value.

Comment: Then give us enough information to debug your problem.

Comment: And don't spam tags. Only one of the 5 tags you used is relevant to your question.